# Possible bug with .net winforms, or am I just missing something? GDI object leak

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi

Could someone please tell me what is going wrong?

After removing tons of code to find our GDI object leak (using task manager and watching the "GDI Objects" column grow to 10,000 and our app crashing) I reduced the code down to only .net code without any custom business code.  We are still getting the issue.

I created a test app to replicate the issue, which has the following basic behavior.

- Open the a form 150 times  (150 is nothing special, just a number large enough to easily see "stuck" handles). A timer on the form will close the form
  after 1 second
- Run the Garbage collector (not really necessary, but can help get rid of the "good" or "working" objects that are not part of the issue)
- Observe manually the GDI Object count of the app (you should do this before and after you open the form 150 times.) Before I run the test I usually get a count of 36, after the test it is about 190.  Ever time I run the test this count increases by about 150.

Now the form that is being launched 150 times is setup in a specific way (Lets call the form "BadForm".  The is a static datatable the is bound to a combobox on the form.

BadForm has a comboBox on it, and a timer.  Here is the code for the form:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace GDIObjectLeakTest
{
  public partial class MyForm :Form
  {
    public static DataTable CachedNodeType = new DataTable();

    public MyForm()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
      this.Font = new Font("Modern No. 20", 8.249999F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))); ;
      comboBox1.DataSource = CachedNodeType;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Close();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the main form of the app that runs the test.  It has 2 buttons on it.  Button1 runs the BadForm 150 times.  Button 2 runs the garbage collector 100 times (Once or twice isn't good enough for me I guess) (I'm using the Garbage Collector just to proove there is/isn't a problem).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
      //new SearchForm().Show();
      new MyForm().Show();
    }
  } catch(Exception ee)
  {
    throw;
  }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `Dispose` on your `MyForm` when you are done using it. You shouldn't rely on the Garbage Collector to do that cleanup.

Comment: I do not believe this is the issue, as if I change any one thing in the setup everything works as I expect (remove the font from the base form, or remove the assignment to the datasource, or change the assignment to a datatable.copy(), or get rid of the event handler.)  Anyone of those things changing and all the GDI handles get returned properly. 

The reason why I call the Garbage Collector in my test is that if everything is working correctly the handles may not get returned immediatly because the Garbage Collector hasn't ran yet.  When this happens I can't tell if the problem exists.

Comment: Is there additional code you aren't showing us?  Based on the code shown the Forms are the only GDI objects I cans see that would leak, properly disposing of them would prevent that leak.

Comment: I didn't show the designer files.

Comment: I updated the Code above to show all the code for the form, I also was able to remove the baseform.

Why is it the font is causing this issue.  I can understand how the static object may be causing the issue, but it is only when the font is set on the form.

Comment: Oh, and I also setup my test to also call .Dispose() on the form.  It doesn't help.

Comment: Post the code with the Dispose.  I am going to guess this is connected to the fact you are making 150 references to the same Font ( there is no good reason for this ).

Comment: @Ramhound that is how it works in winforms.  I only moved the code from the designer to the .cs to make it clearer for others to see.

Comment: If you add this.Font.Dispose on the form close event, does it correct the issue? I think instantiating the font and not explicitly disposing of it might be the problem. Not sure why though. The form's dispose event is suppose to call the dispose event on everything that implements IDisposable I thought.

Comment: @SpectralGhost calling this.Font.Dispose does not fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with that font.  Fonts are cached in Winforms, I'd guess that the cache manager is getting confused somehow by that font and always creates a new cache entry.  You can't otherwise reset that cache yourself.  Ditch the font.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the font specificly, just the fact that I am assigning the font.  What I am doing is the STANDARD way of changing the font of a form.  The ONLY thing different here (and I don't did this to make it easier for others to digest) was move the code from the designer.cs to the .cs.  

Remember if you change any 1 of the 3 things, everything works correctly.  It isn't just 1 of the things causing the issue, it is the combination.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the top of your dispose method (in the designer file):

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I am long past working on this issue (I have moved projects, and companies since the time of this posting) but I will still comment on this.

I do not like editing designer files.  It is to fragile of a change.  VS will rewrite the entire file frequently and it is too difficult to tell that that line is removed accidentally.

I feel the problem that I have here is the binding of a static object.  I should of probably tried you line suggestion in perhaps the Closing/Closed event.  That might fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential issues here:

1. If you create an instance of an object that implements `IDisposable`, you must call the Dispose method on it, or wrap its use in a `using` block.  **Form implements IDisposable**, so your code should look like the following:

   ```
       using (Form myform = new Form())
       {
           myform.Show();
       }   //frees resource by calling Dispose automatically
   ```

   otherwise, you will see the memory leaks you see here, because you are creating new instances of your Form, but then you are never freeing its resources.  Garbage collection might eventually free up Windows resources for you in WinForms, due to the way that finalizers are written in the BCL, but calling Dispose will do it immediately.
2. You are creating a new `Font` object and assigning it to the Font property each time your form is initialized.  Not that this is necessarily bad (designer generated code does this copiously), but each new `Font` instance occupies a GDI handle, which will not be freed automatically unless you call Font.Dispose.  My guess is that you are leaving another Font object behind that might not be getting Disposed properly.  You may want to optimize this in some way (such as by sharing a Font instance) if you are making **huge** numbers of these objects.  [In at least one case](http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/gdi-memory-leak-in-windows-forms/), not calling Dispose on fonts will cause this memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Font object which is an GDI object and not disposed until you dispose it.
Either use Font object with using statement, or call Font.Dispose on FormClose event.

Comment: that is how font objects are created and used in the designer files.  I just summarized what was happening and formatted it like this.

The error has to do with the static object and the form not being able to dispose itself..