# Why application throws error "Value cannot be null" on ShowDialog method?

Tags: c#

I spent 5 days trying to solve this issue but I failed.

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms. I built an application which consists of 20 forms. The application starts with 2 `forms` (`SplashScreen` and `MainForm`) the `SplashScreen` form has a timer and ProgressBar and the `MainForm` has 10 buttons each of which opens other forms. When this application runs it first load the `SplashScreen` form and when the `progressBar` completes it checks if `System.txt` file exists or not, if it exists it loads the `MainForm` form:

**SplashScreen Form:**

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    // This is a timer for progressBar:
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if(progressBar1.Value==100)
        {

            timer1.Stop(); //it stops when progressBar completes.
            CheckFile();    // this method will be called when progressBar completes           

        }
    }

    public void CheckFile()
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Folder1\System.txt"))
        {
            // if the file exist Main form will be opened 

            MainForm _MainForm = new MainForm();
            this.Hide();
            _MainForm.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error the program throws after 9 hours of running:

[image: screenshot]

What is the issue:

Now when I run the program the `SplashScreen` loads and then it opens the `MainForm` (because `System.txt` exists) and the application works very well, however after exactly 9 hours of running the application  it throws error "Value cannot be null" and it points at `ShowDialog` method (as shown on screenshot). Note that the error occurs even if I don't use the application (I just press F5 and wait 9 hours till the error occurs).

When I set the application to start with the `MainForm` first (on `Program.cs`) the application works without error for very long hours, I mean it works for a days without this  error. The error occurs only when the program starts with `splashScreen` Form (`Application.Run(new SplashScreen())`)

What I tried to solve the issue:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
    }
}
```

- I tried `Show()` method instead of `ShowDialog()` and the application throws same error but this time the error points at `Application.Run(new SplashScreen())` on the `Programe.cs` (see above).
- Also I tried `MainForm _MainForm = new MainForm() { Owner = this };`
- Also I tried `_MainForm.ShowDialog(this);`
- Also I tried `_MainForm.ShowDialog(); Application.DoEvents();`

  All what I tried resulted in same error "Value cannot be null" and the error points at `_MainForm.ShowDialog();`

Now 5 days I have been trying to solve this issue but I couldn't, every time I run the application with `SplashScreen` it gives this error exactly after 9 hours (why 9 hours?). I understand that a variable can be null not a method, so how can `ShowDialog` be null ? Anyone knows why `ShowDialog` throws error after long runtime? I will be happy to hear other ideas in how can I open `MainForm` from `SplashScreen` and keep it open for long time?

Please take 5 minutes to help me I am really desperate, every little help could solve this issue. Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Why are you loading the mainform as a modal? The splash screen close will not get called until the modal method returns, which wont happen until the modal closes. Try just using `_mainForm.Show();`

Comment: You seem to execute `MainForm _MainForm = new MainForm()` multiple times. You probably should not do that, just create it once, and use the same instance each time you need it again.

Comment: @ Wjdavis5 . I am new to c# I dont know what you mean by modal? I already tried using _mainForm.Show(); but it throws same error as i said.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? This might give some insights into what's throwing the error.

Comment: The problem clearly lies deeper. It's not `Show` or `ShowDialog` that causes the problem (directly). They wouldn't throw an `ArgumentNullException`. It must be thrown by some method, or constructor, that's executed within `MainForm` itself once it's initializing. Get the full stracktrace, and post the code of `MainForm` itself..

Comment: @ Wimmel. No, I execute MainForm _MainForm = new MainForm() only one time once the progressBar completes. I already did what you said but it throws same error ( I just created it once, and used the same instance each time) , still same error.

Comment: @amura.cxg .I am sorry I am new to c# , can you tell me more about stack trace? thank you

Comment: @Kate In the exception dialog if you click "View Details" a new window will open up. If you expand the first element there's an entry marked as "StackTrace". [Here's](http://imgur.com/a/r31n4) a few images of what that looks like.

Comment: @amura.cxg . There is no "View Details" section on the exception dialog as shown in the screenshot above, any idea where to find it? tnx

Comment: We just don't have enough code from either SplashScreen or MainForm to determine what is causing your issue.

Comment: @ LarsTech . I can't post the MainForm Code because it is very long. The MainForm Code reads and writes data into sql server and the form has many instances of other forms to open and close, that is all the code. splashScreen code is shown above.

Comment: Then try: `Application.Run(new MainForm());this.Close();` instead.

Comment: Why don't you make the _MainForm static and be done with it?

Comment: @ Movsar Bekaev. I am sorry I am new to c#, can you tell me how can I make it static? tnx

Comment: I would guess that this is related to a timer or something like that, possibly involving a `short`, as the max value of short would be approximately 9 hours in seconds.

Comment: This might be a GDI Object Leak, caused somewhere else in your program. Maybe you can look at
[How to debug GDI Object Leaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8306253/33499). [Stacktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36652601/33499). @Kate, when you reply, don't add a space after the `@`!